# How can I visualize the type hierarchy of large/deep thrift object/types?

Tags: json, treeview, visualization, thrift

For many of our services, we have large thrift IDLs where the types can get really deep. However, it's hard to *visualize* how the various types are related/nested.

What's the easiest way to visualize the object graphs of the various thrift objects? Is there anything that could convert the thrift IDL types into a JSON pretty print, for example? Or an IDE extension which can show a tree diagram of the type hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) generator that you could try.

```
 thrift  -gen gv  <idlfile>
```

Here's an example that I used a while ago for some other purposes:

[image: graphviz outpout from IDL below]

```
namespace * Testcase

struct BasicNeeds {
  1 : optional double beerLiters = 1.23
  2 : optional string beerName = "Heineken"
}

enum Steak {
  Raw = 0,
  Rare = 1,
  Medium = 2,
  WellDone = 3,
  Coal = 4
}

enum Requirement {
  SpeakMyLanguage = 0,
  FreeCoffee = 1,
  GoodService = 2,
  TakeCreditCards = 3,
  AllYouCanEat = 4
}

typedef list< Requirement>  FurtherRequirements

struct TableSize {
  1 : optional i32 Width = 20
  2 : optional i32 Length = 40
}

struct PlaceOrder {
  1 : required BasicNeeds BasicNeeds
  2 : required Steak Kind = Steak.Medium
  3 : optional FurtherRequirements FurtherRequirements
  4 : bool FirstVisit = false
  5 : optional TableSize Table  
}

union OrderResult {
  1 : bool Success
  2 : bool SorryOutOfSteaks
  3 : bool SorryClosed
  4 : double UnpaidBillFromLastVisit
}

exception DinerError {
  1 :  string  Msg
}

service Diner {
  OrderResult PlaceOrder( 1 : PlaceOrder request)   throws ( 1: DinerError rex),
  OrderResult PlaceOrder2( 1 : PlaceOrder request, 2: i32 numberOfSteaks)   throws ( 1: DinerError rex),
  PlaceOrder TryReversed( 1 : OrderResult request)
}
```